# pastebinit how to post pasties with login info?

Tags: linux, unix

Not so many manuals for this package.

I want to post pasties to pastebin.com under my username. so

> pastebinit -u myuser -p mypassword file.py

doesn't work, it's not logging in... why?

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
$ pastebinit -u myuser -p mypassword -i file.py
```

**Edit:** Try a different host:

```
$ ./pastebinit -i file.py -b http://paste.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Did not work for me either. In fact it seems that most of the switches are ignored t,m,u,p have no bearing on what gets pasted.